# Why am I able to use the controllers array in a controller?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am playing arround with ExtJS4.2. I added a `controllers` array to a simple controller (no I am not inheriting fom application) and they all get loaded (but not initialized).

But within the API there is not `controllers` property for `Ext.app.Controller`. That they don't get initialized is only a sidenote and not that important for me.

**I just wonder why they get loaded at all and if this behavior is something I can rely on?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a side effect from MVC refactoring in 4.2, and being so it was neither completely implemented nor properly documented. We'll fix that in 4.2.1 most probably but I can't guarantee that it won't change.

Comment: Again about 4.2 Maybe you can take a look here to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358010/use-and-function-of-the-new-ext-app-eventdomain

Comment: I really like this behaviour. It allows to define dependend constructors in a controller instead of loading them each. The downside is that the controllers don't get initialized so I need to do this myself. I tried to read the source and didn't fully understand why this happends. The application controller inherit the controller and not vice versa. If it is not to complex I would love it if you can explain how this happends. I guess it is due to the inheritance?

Comment: No, in fact the reason is quite simple: I didn't think of it when I refactored Controller/Application relationship, and didn't implement it the way it would work. That's it, no secret sauce. It has to be done on the Application level, because `Controller.init()` is called with Application object as parameter, which is not available any earlier than Application itself gets initialized. I need to think this through because if we're not careful here we can get a nice race condition and that would only make things worse.